# Run cucumber steps in loop ONLY for few steps

Tags: cucumber

Is it possible to loop ONLY identified steps in cucumber scenario

For instance in the following example if I want to loop other steps except first. Because first step should run ONLY once

```
Scenario Outline: submit guess
  Given I am logged as Admin
  And the secret code is <code> 
  When I guess <guess>
  Then the mark should be <mark>

Examples: all colors correct
| code    | guess   | mark |
| r g y c | r g y c | bbbb |
| r g y c | r g c y | bbww |
| r g t g | r g w e | bbpp |
```

Is this possible in cucumber? Currently it runs all the steps four times as per the parameter values.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `Ruby` or `Java`

Comment: Thanks for your response Bala. I am using groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily achieved using variables that act like a flag. Something like this

```
Before do
  if !$ran_once
   $ran_once = false
  end
end

Given(/^I am logged as Admin$/) do
  do something unless $ran_once
  $ran_once = true
end
```

Refer https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#hooks

Answer (score 2):

A Scenario Outline is meant to run the whole "scenario" but with different data each time. While you could setup a flag in the before hook, and then flag it the first time the step is run, you are leaking test state. This is generally a bad practice.

Instead it would be better to just use a scenario that uses a table for the validation step:

```
    Scenario: Submitting guesses
      Given I am logged as Admin
      Then my guesses display the correct colors:
        | code    | guess   | mark |
        | r g y c | r g y c | bbbb |
        | r g y c | r g c y | bbww |
        | r g t g | r g w e | bbpp |
```

Comment: For reasons beyond my control I must use existing Excel Files as data inputs.

Why is looping over multiple steps using data inside the gherkin file ok (as in Scenario Outline), but getting data from outside (using Excel spreadsheets in Hooks) bad practice?